# zendframework 3 - identity view helper error

Tags: zend-framework3

I try to use identity view helper in my layout.phtml

```
$this->identity();
```

but get this error:

```
No AuthenticationServiceInterface instance provided in  vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\Helper\Identity.php on line 38
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually setup `Zend-Authentication` and registered it within your `services` of the `ServiceManager`?

Because the factory for the `IdentityHelper` will set the `AuthenticationService`.

See: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc-plugin-identity/blob/1.1.0/src/IdentityFactory.php#L27-L31

```
    if ($container->has(AuthenticationService::class)) {
        $plugin->setAuthenticationService($container->get(AuthenticationService::class));
    } elseif ($container->has(AuthenticationServiceInterface::class)) {
        $plugin->setAuthenticationService($container->get(AuthenticationServiceInterface::class));
    }
```

Register the AuthenticationService within your Applications module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService::class => \Application\Service\Factory\AuthenticationServiceFactory::class,
    ]
],
```

Create a factory for your AuthenticationService where you tell the service which adapter to use on how to check if the identity is valid. See https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-authentication/intro/#usage